# Rest: Sending List of Enums does not send all data

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, jax-rs, json-serialization

**1. BACKEND**

In my backend (SpringBoot) I am sending list of enums:

```
@RequestMapping("getMyEnum")
public List<MyEnum> getMyEnum() {
    return Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
}
```

Here is MyEnum:

```
public enum MyEnum {

  A("bla1"),
  B("bla2");  

  private String value;

  MyEnum(String value) {
...
```

**2. FRONTEND**

In frontend (angular2) I am receiving this list in my ng2 component:

```
 MY_ENUMS: MyEnum[];
 ...
 this.http.get('/util/getClassifications')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(myEnums => {
    this.MY_ENUMS = myEnums;
  });
```

Here is class MyEnum:

```
export class MyEnum {
    value: string;
}
```

**3. RESULT**

After running the code:

```
MY_ENUMS contains ["A", "B"]
```

But I would expect:

```
MY_ENUMS will contains [ "A" : { "value" : "bla1"}, 
                         "B" : { "value" : "bla2"}]
```

Comment: You can see the network log for the format of data being sent. It seems the server is doing this serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default `Jackson` (the JSON mapper which is used in Spring Boot) serializes only the enum names. To adapt your enum serialization - and treat it as every other object - add to your enum the following `JsonFormat` annotation and it will map all properties of the enum as well.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum MyEnum
```

---

**Update**

1. Make sure your enum provides all getters.

   ```
   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
   public enum MyEnum {

      A("bla1", 1),
      B("bla2", 2);

      private String valueA;
      private long valueB;

      MyEnum(String valueA, long valueB) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
        this.valueB = valueB;
      }

      public String getValueA() {
        return valueA;
      }

      public long getValueB() {
        return valueB;
      }
   }
   ```
2. You can test you serialization with

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(MyEnum.A));
   ```
3. The result is

   ```
   {"valueA":"bla1","valueB":1}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The enum must also have getters for its properties.